# FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist getting error

Tags: android, firebase, android-service

Hi I am trying to get data on background service of Android. But I am getting this error. Here is my code:

```
public class FirebaseBackgroundService extends Service {

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private ValueEventListener handler;
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("chats");

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        handler = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                postNotify(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        myRef.addValueEventListener(handler);
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2862)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1427)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. 
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at bagga2.example.com.liiv.services.FirebaseBackgroundService.<init>(FirebaseBackgroundService.java:30)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2859)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1427) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Include the error that is logged

Comment: I had the same issue, nothing seemed to help until they updated the sdk. If you are still facing the issue please update to sdk 9.2.1 in which this issue has been addressed.

Answer (score 8):

If your component (service most likely) does not live in the app's default process you have to manually initialize `FirebaseApp` like so:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, FirebaseOptions.fromResource(context));
```

Do this before accessing any other Firebase API.

#### Implementation Background

Every process instantiates their own set of classes. For example each of your processes has its own `Application` object. Therefore `Application` is a singleton *within one process*.

`FirebaseApp` in default process is initialized via `FirebaseInitProvider` class which is a `ContentProvider` that is created at application start *only in default process*. (The `<provider>` element in manifest is merged in automatically.)

Please note that the `<provider>` element attribute `android:multiprocess="true"` would have no effect as the provider itself has no clients who'd like to interact with it.

#### Example #1: Init Everywhere

If you want access to a `FirebaseApp` everywhere in your app an obvious place to put init code is your `Application` class.

```
try {
    FirebaseApp.getInstance()
} catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, FirebaseOptions.fromResource(context));
}
```

I said "obvious" not "good". I have no idea how this impacts individual Firebase services (such as crash reporting) or how resource intense this operation is to do even in processes where you don't need Firebase.

#### Example #2: App Widgets (Init Only When Needed)

According to [`AppWidgetProvider docs`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#AppWidgetProvider) you either create widget UI in a configuration activity or by receiving an  `onUpdate` callback. Which means you probably need access to `FirebaseApp` in both those places. So call the code from Example #1 in both of them before accessing firebase.

Comment: Why we have to specifically initialize the Firebase if component not live in app default's process. What happens in case of default application process. In this case where does Firebase gets initialized?

Comment: Thanks for details. I am facing same issue when I try to host a widget of application on home screen and widget in my application runs on its own process. If possible please let me know the best place to initialize the FirebaseApp via widget. I can't initialize it in Custom Application class since for application it automatically gets initialized by FirebaseInitProvider

Comment: If I add following code in Custom Application class than will there be any issue:
if (FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()) {
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(mContext, FirebaseOptions.fromResource(mContext));
        }

Comment: @SagarTrehan Initializing Fireabse everywhere is wasteful. Only do it when you actually need it. See the Example #2 in updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I am trying this and will let you know if any issue

Comment: I tried initializing FirebaseApp in onUpdate() callbacks of AppWidgetProvider but it didn't work. Since onUpdate() method gets invoked on app default process and then WidgetRemoteService gets created on its own process. So in this case when Custom Application class gets instantiates and we have some code in it that requires FirebaseApp to be initialize then IllegalStateException is thrown. I believe in my case Example 1 will work correctly.

Comment: What's a WidgetRemoteService? Just initialize it before you actually access firebase. Wherever that is.

Comment: WidgetRemoteService is my custom implementation of RemoteViewService. I tried overriding its onCreate() and initializing FirebaseApp but it didn't work because Custom Application class gets instantiates before onCreate() invokes.

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate objects in lifecycle callbacks.

```
FirebaseDatabase database;
private ValueEventListener handler;
DatabaseReference myRef;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference("chats");
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: I tried . Still having same error..But same methods are running on other classes not on service class

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you have [installed Firebase SDK correctly](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and that you have added the line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

at the bottom of your app level `build.gradle` file. Then rebuild the project, that solved the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/), it shouldn't be required for the services I was using, but this issue resolved when I added the SHA-1 Debug Key to the online setup for the app. Click on the Settings Gear -> Project Settings. Then Add SHA1 at the bottom. See [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth) to get Debug SHA1 Fingerprint

[image]

Comment: I am stuck with the same issue, nothing seems to help here.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late but you have to add this in your `app` gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

at your project level gradle.

Answer (score 0):

please check if google-services.json file is added in your project or not , if not add it and the rebuild project..