# Firebase analytics event not show up on firebase console

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

I have implement `firebase analytics` in my app, but not show up any event or log in fire base console.

Add bellow code in each fragment in `onCreateView()` method.

```
private void addFragmentInFirebaseAnalytics() {

    FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(getContext());
    FragmentItem fragmentItem = new FragmentItem();
    fragmentItem.setFragmentId(Constant.FM_ID_MOIST_AIR);
    fragmentItem.setFragmentName(MoistAirActivity.class.getSimpleName());

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, fragmentItem.getFragmentId());
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, fragmentItem.getFragmentName());

    //Logs an app event.
    firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
    Log.d(TAG,"bundle >>"+bundle);
}
```

Used dependency is :

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
```

used plugin :

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Its work fine and show log like this in debug console,

```
    09-14 12:30:42.967 D/FA      ( 8821): Logging event (FE): select_content, Bundle
[{_o=app, _ev=item_id, item_name=MoistAirActivity, content_type=Navigation Menu,
 _err=4}]
09-14 12:30:42.977 V/FA      ( 8821): Using measurement service
09-14 12:30:42.977 V/FA      ( 8821): Connecting to remote service
09-14 12:30:43.217 D/FA      ( 8821): Connected to remote service
09-14 12:30:43.217 V/FA      ( 8821): Processing queued up service tasks: 1
09-14 12:30:43.217 E/FA      ( 8821): Task exception on worker thread: java.lang
.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. : com.goo
gle.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzt.zzEd(Unknown Source)
09-14 12:30:48.217 V/FA      ( 8821): Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurem
entService
```

but not show any uploading message in debug console and firebase console after 24 hours,

So, whats wrong here ? please help.

Comment: It takes few hours for the analytics to update and display records. Read this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347991/how-much-time-does-it-take-for-firebase-analytics-first-report

Comment: But i am waiting 4 to 5 days but not showing any data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i resolved this problem by replacing `tools:node="replace" to tools:node="merge"` and add `tools:replace="android:label"` in menifest file.

Reference : [FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342403/firebaseapp-with-name-default-doesnt-exist)

Comment: why we need this here? Any idea? @vishal gandhiya

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that could be going on here.  You will see more diagnostic messages if you run:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
```

and if your test device has Google Play Services installed, also run:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
```

Those commands will display more information in your logcat.  Are there any errors from FA or FA-SVC on application startup?

Comment: Now every thing is working fine and logged firebase message, but data not upload on firebase console and generate exception E/FA: Task exception on worker thread: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist. : com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzt.zzbpu(Unknown Source)

Comment: Take a look at this answer and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37342403/firebaseapp-with-name-default-doesnt-exist

Comment: Have you tried the ideas in this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37531749/firebaseapp-with-name-default-doesnt-exist-getting-error

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

in the  AndroidManifest.xml.

I've not specified any tools attribute.