# Android Firebase console doesn't show logs

Tags: android, firebase, logging, analytics, firebase-analytics

```
  firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this)
  val bundle = Bundle()
  bundle.putString("permission", " granted")
  firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("screen_one", bundle)
```

This is how I log an event through `FirebaseAnalytics`, although I can see them in Android studio logs

`: Logging event: origin=app,name=screen_one,params=Bundle[{permission= granted, firebase_event_origin(_o)=app, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=`

In the Firebase console I navigate to `Project Overview -> Events` but I can not see the logs.

[image]

Comment: please wait for sometime if its newly added or check out this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306870/firebase-analytics-event-not-show-up-on-firebase-console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will take 24 hours to display the log in Firebase Analytics. 
[See This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37348235/8052440)