# Firebase analytics realtime report not working

Tags: android, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have two flavors in my project, and for one flavor Firebase analytics real time report is working sometimes, not consistently, and on another it`s not working at all. I have tried with with two different devices and the results are the same

I have included libraries
`implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx"`
`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'`
`implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.1.0')` (Not working with 32.2.0 version)

Added soogle services plugin

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

Added folllowing lines of code for logging events

```
var firebaseAnalytics: FirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context)
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.APP_OPEN, null)
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("custom", null)

firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("background3"){
                                    param("value",dataSnapshot.getValue().toString())
                                    param("name", com.iwedia.google_reference.BuildConfig.FLAVOR)
                                }
```

And ran these instructions in terminal

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
adb setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.company.app.fbtest
```

For other flavor package name is com.company.app

I have checked out some other questions on stack overflow
[Firebase analytics event not show up on firebase console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39306870/firebase-analytics-event-not-show-up-on-firebase-console)
[Firebase Analytics Debug View does not show anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42769236/firebase-analytics-debug-view-does-not-show-anything)
Answers on this questions have not helped me

Logging in Logcat works just fine